# Sending a List of heterogeneous objects

Tags: servicestack, protobuf-net

I have a series of "Messages" to be sent to a server application from a mobile client.
Each message has some common information (MAC, timestamp etc) and its 
So `ObjMessage` is the base class that has a `MessageInfo` and a `TransactionInfo` class, then I have a `ObjReqMsg1` and `ObjReqMsg2` that differ for a int and string property, just for test.

// Messaging classes

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class MessageInfo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string MAC { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string version { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public Guid guidMessage { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public DateTime timeGenerated { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class TransactionInfo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string user1 { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string user2 { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public DateTime timeOperation { get; set; }
}


[ProtoContract]
public class ObjMessage
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public TransactionInfo transactionInfo { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public MessageInfo messageInfo { get; set; }
}
```

// LIST of different messages

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class ObjReqMsg1 : ObjMessage
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int intValue { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ObjReqMsg2 : ObjMessage
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string stringValue { get; set; }
}


[ProtoContract]
public class ReqListMessages : IReturn<RespListMessages>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<ObjMessage> objsReqMessage { get; set; }
}
```

All my tests are done with json and protocol buffers, and sending single messages of lists of eterogeneous messages works.

My questions are:
1) my idea, instead of sending ten `ObjReqMsg1` requests, is to make just one request with a `List<ObjReqMsg1>`, to save on network calls. It works and it actually saves some time, does it make sense? Or it would be more correct to make the 10 calls?

2) Then, if it makes sense and is the right path, i thought it would be great instead of making two `List<ObjReqMsg1>` and `List<ObjReqMsg2>` calls, to make a single `List<ObjMessage>` call, and on the server check if each `ObjMessage` is `ObjReqMsg1` or `ObjReqMsg2` , cast and act accordingly.Is it feasible?

If it is, what am I doing wrong, because, when I create a `List<ObjMessage>` adding 3 `ObjReqMsg1` and 3 `ObjReqMsg2`, and checking with inspector that `intValue` and `stringValue` are present, when I do:

```cs
string serialized = ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString<ReqListMessages>(reqListMessage);
```

I don't find `intValue` and `stringValue` serialized.

And obviously on the server side I receive a list of 6 `ObjMessage`, instead of a list of 3 `ObjReqMsg1` + 3 `ObjReqMsg2`.

Can you help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: in most API scenarios, sending fewer chunkier requests is usually the simplest way of improving performance; "does it make sense" depends on the context, but if it makes sense *to you* then: probably

2: add `[ProtoInclude(5, typeof(ObjReqMsg1))]` and `[ProtoInclude(6, typeof(ObjReqMsg2))]` to the `class ObjMessage` declaration, and try again.

Re "cast and act accordingly" - you might also consider polymorphism, i.e. a `virtual` or `abstract` method on `ObjMessage` that `ObjReqMsg1` and `ObjReqMsg2` can `override`. Then you don't have to do anything; you just call `obj.TheMethod(args)`.

Comment: thanks, adding the ProtoInclude made eveything work, with protobuf.
But trying to make it work also with the servicestack json serializer I found many answers of mythz who discourages my approach (DTOs not well defined), so I'll probably go with a DTO with a List<ObjReqMsg1> and a List<ObjReqMsg2> instead of a single List<ObjMessage>.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a variant (i.e union) for clients to better expect the possible data variability. Otherwise, your clients will be coupled to the service.